# Mulitple certificates vs. multiple domain names in one - AWS Certificate Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-certificate-manager

I just started using the AWS certificate manager and I was curious to see if there was a difference between creating multiple certificates, for example:

```
One for: mydomain.com
Another for *.mydomain.com
```

Or if it would be better to make one domain that **contains both**:

```
mydomain.com
AND
*.mydomain.com
```

Thanks!

Comment: Most wildcard certs ‘should’ be configured to have the root domain as an alternate subject - which covers this specific case. While there are exceptions, this matches most web-facing site usages: foo.com or www.foo.com, eg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a single ALB or CloudFront distribution you will need to have these as a single certificate.

Ideally I would use the single certificate for all domains as it easier to manage.

Comment: Exactly, always depends on the usecase ;)

Comment: I see, so for my case, I want to have a cloudfront distribution for mydomain.com and connect a load balancer to *.mydomain.com ... thus, would I have to create 2 certificates?

Comment: So you'd need an ACM certificate in ue-east-1 for CloudFront, and then a certificate in the same region as your load balancer. If the load balancer is in us-east-1 you would not need a second.